# How can I hook up my outlook calendar to a website?

Tags: outlook, synchronization, calendar, feed

I want to publish some kind of feed that outlook can read and use to populate its calendar. I'm not having any luck discovering how to do this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was an iCalendar feed link, which works like RSS and updates dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a way to sync them directly. However I know you can hook up your Outlook Calendar to link to Google Calendar, and due to the nature of Google Calendar there's alot you can do with that data:

[Linking Outlook and Google Calendars](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=89955)

[Linking Google Calendar with RSS Feeds](http://blog.lib.umn.edu/ayubx003/dividebyzero/2008/08/18/customize_google_calendar_rss.html)